# <input type="date" name="hoge">を未入力のまま送信した場合は、NULLを受け取りたい

Tags: php, html

**該当HTML**

```
<input type="date" name="hoge">
```

**条件**
入力必須にはしたくない

**やりたいこと**
未入力のまま送信した場合は、NULLを受け取りたい

---

**質問**
・`<input type="date">`を未入力のまま送信した場合の値は何になりますか？　空文字？
・未入力のまま送信した場合の値を「NULL」もしくは「送信しない」にすることは出来ますか？
・受信側で、「空文字」を受け取ってから「NULL」へ変換するしかない？

Comment: isset や emptyを組み合わせて  if(isset($_POST['hoge'])){if(empty($_POST['hoge'])) echo 'empty';else echo 'none empty';} のようにチェックや「NULL」へ変換を行うとよいかも

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> を未入力のまま送信した場合の値は何になりますか？　空文字？

空文字になります。

> ・未入力のまま送信した場合の値を「NULL」もしくは「送信しない」にすることは出来ますか？
>   ・受信側で、「空文字」を受け取ってから「NULL」へ変換するしかない？

HTMLは空文字を送信してしまうのでJavascriptでPHP側でnull判定をさせるという方法ができます。

PHPでnullと判定させるには、そもそも送信させないという制御が必要なので条件でinputを追加したり消したりという処理をいれるのが良いと思います。

```js
$(".send_text").on("click", function(){
  var send_text_value = $(".send_text:checked").val();
  if (send_text_value == 1) {
    $("<input type='text' name='send_text_any' id='send_text_any'>").prependTo("#send_form")
  }else {
    $("#send_text_any").remove();
  }
});

$("#send_form").submit(function(){
  alert($('form').serialize());
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="post" id="send_form">
  <label><input type="radio" name="send_text" class="send_text" value="1">テキストを送信する</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="send_text" class="send_text" value="0" checked="checked">テキストを送信しない</label>
  <input type="submit" value="送信" >
</form>
```

ただ上の処理はあくまで、
（1）null
（2）空文字
を区別したいという処理のために行います。

もし、単純に空文字をnullとして処理したいということであれば受け手側で空文字をnullに変換するのが良いでしょう。
というのは結局POSTする値はブラウザの処理になるので、Javascriptで空文字をnullになるように制御しても、改ざん（空文字送信）で結局はサーバサイドでサニタイズ（null化）が必要になります。

Comment: 回答を読んで改めて思ったのですが、POSTはブラウザ処理なので、そもそもnull自体を送信できないのですね。アドバイス通り、受信側で空文字をnullに変換することにします